# Difference between color and colorscheme in VIM

Tags: vim

The directories in my *~/.vim* directory are

```
autoload  bundle  colors
```

`autoload` contains `pathogen.vim`

`bundle` contains `nerdtree  tagbar  vim-colors-solarized`

`colors` contains `adobe.vim  autumnleaf_modified.vim  autumnleaf.vim  codeburn.vim  tango-desert.vim  wood.vim`

Now my *.vimrc* contains the following lines

```
execute pathogen#infect()
set t_Co=16
set background=light
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized
set background=dark
```

The line `colorscheme solarized`  chooses the colorscheme solarized from bundle folder.

If I were to open the editor `vim test.c` and then set

```
:color wood
```

it selects wood color scheme from `colors` folder.

What is the difference between the colors for VIM chosen from colors folder and bundle folder?

Comment: `:colorscheme solarized`, `:color solarized`, `:colo solarized` are all exactly the same, they just have the command name abbreviated to different degrees.

Answer (score 5):

Vim has something called `runtimepath`: a list of top level directories where to look for runtime files.

By default, Vim will look for a number of subdirectories under the directories in `runtimepath` but, as you can see from the list under `:help rtp`, there's no default `bundle/` directory: that `bundle/` directory is a Pathogen convention.

What Pathogen does is relatively simple in theory: it adds whatever directory it finds directly under `bundle/` to the `runtimepath`, making their content available to Vim.

Each plugin directory you add to your `bundle/` directory acts like a mini `$HOME/.vim/`: it may contain any or all of the default directories Vim expects to find in `$HOME/.vim/` like `colors/`, `autoload/`, `after/`, …

Your plugins are all located under the same directory, each in its own subdirectory, sandboxed, easy to remove, modify or update, tidy.

Thanks to Pathogen, Vim is thus able to look for color schemes in `bundle/whatever/colors/` as well as in the default `colors/`.

Practically speaking, the only difference between those color schemes is their location.